# surfing all website and all links opens in same webview

Tags: android, android-webview

when I create webview application to view any website on same webview not browser it works fine but when I click on any link in that website it opens in browser ? how to load all internal links/pages/sections when user click on them at same webview ?

Answer (score 6):

Java version:
You only need to set a `WebViewClient` for your `WebView` and then all links will be opened it the same `WebView`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private class myCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    //here load the url in your webview
    webview.loadUrl(url);

    return true;
    }
```

And this for set in your webview

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new myCustomWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version.

```
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a webViewClient of your own.

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

in the webViewClient you can override the  shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method to be like:

```
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

I hope you find it helpful.