# Open hyperlink on webview after user click on link

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new in xamarin, I added a webview to my layout and show a responsive website in this webview. It works great but when I click on any links in this web view my device asked me select your browser to open link. I need to open any hyperlinks in same webview. I dont want device asked open link in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to set a WebViewClient for your WebView and then all links will be opened it the same WebView:

```
WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Resource: [surfing all website and all links opens in same webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483690/surfing-all-website-and-all-links-opens-in-same-webview)